# TyperError 'int' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python-3.x, sorting, typeerror, bubble-sort

I am attempting to make a sort (based off of the bubble sort) which will alphabetically sort words. However, it keeps coming up with:

> TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable.

It says the error is in line 25 and 28, but I can't figure out what I am doing wrong. I am aware I can use `.sort()`, but I want to write my own sorting function. Any suggestions?

The code is:

```
inp = input(r"Input: ")

inp = inp.split(" ")


def sort(inp):
    fin = False
    while not fin:
        fin = True
        pos = 0
        for i in range(0,len(inp)-1):
            if len(inp[i]) < len(inp[i+1]):
                overLen = len(inp[i])
            else:
                overLen = len(inp[i])
            if pos == overLen:
                if len(inp[i]) < len(inp[i+1]):
                    inp[pos] = inp[i]
                    inp[pos+1] = inp[i+1]
                else:
                    inp[pos] = inp[i+1]
                    inp[pos+1] = inp[i]
                fin = False
            elif inp[i[pos]] < inp[i+1[pos]]:
                inp[pos] = inp[i]
                inp[pos+1] = inp[i+1]
                fin = False
            elif inp[i[pos]] > inp[i+1[pos]]:
                inp[pos] = inp[i+1]
                inp[pos+1] = inp[i]
                fin = False
            else:
                pos += 1
                fin = False
    return(inp)

print(sort(inp))
```

Comment: i is an int, so `i[pos]` (and `1[pos]`)  can't work

Answer (score 1):

`i` is an integer, `inp` is the array you're sorting. You index the array, not the integers.

If I understand what you want to do correctly, these are the things you need to change:

Add indexes to get the offset you want like this:
`inp[i[pos]]` -> `inp[i+pos]`
`inp[i+1[pos]]` -> `inp[i+1+pos]`

Comment: i is also an int (`for i in range(0,len(inp)-1):`)

Comment: @fredtantini fixed